# What does running "show slave status" on a master server show?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication

We are using monitoring software that is throwing an error saying that `Slave_IO_Running` is returning `No` for replication on our **master** server. It is in fact true that when running `show slave status` on the master server, that `Slave_IO_Running` shows `No` but `Slave_SQL_Running` shows `Yes`.

I understand that the `show slave status` command needs to be run on the slave server, and not the master and that any server can be a master and/or slave. To my knowledge, this server is truly only a master and doesn't serve as a slave to any other server.

I'm wondering why the monitoring software is showing this as a critical error, and if it is any cause for concern. Replication is running smoothly as far as I can tell, but looking to clear up this error from the monitoring software. Am I right in that, if this is the master server, `Slave_IO_Running: No` as well as any other output from `show_slave_status` on the master isn't meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MASTER / SLAVE REPLICATION

In Master/Slave Replication, you should not have any output from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on the Master. If you see any output, it is more than likely stale and no longer needed. You can remove that with the following commands

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE ALL;
```

After running these commands on the Master, you should get this from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

```
mysql> show slave status\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

WARNING !!! : Do not run those commands on the Slave (Breaks Replication)

### MASTER / MASTER REPLICATION

In Master/Master Replication, both Masters are Slaves to Each Other. If your DB Topology is Master/Master Replication, then this is a legitimate error condition. The message `Slave_IO_Runninng: Yes` means there is a DB Connection going to another DB Server and collecting binlog events that have executed on that other DB Server already. When you have `Slave_IO_Runninng: No`, there is no DB Connection back to the other DB Server.

This be remedied with `START SLAVE;` but please find out why (Firewall Issue, Network Outage Between Servers, etc) before running that.

### YOUR ACTUAL QUESTION

You asked

> Am I right in that, if this is the master server, Slave_IO_Running: No as way as any other output from show_slave_status on the master isn't meaningful?

Output from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on a Master that is Master/Slave Replication (and not in Master/Master Replication) is not meaningful. You can run `STOP SLAVE; RESET SLAVE ALL;` on that Master so the monitoring software can stop alerting you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was unaware of the master/master type relationship. Is there a way of checking if the servers are in fact in a master/master replication setup?

Comment: 1) See if `log_slave_updates` is configured (in /etc/my.cnf) on that Master. 2) Look for Relay Logs files on the Master (If you have them check the file timestamp to see how long ago replication was last runnng) 3) Check if there is any Topology management tools looking over the DB Servers (Orchestrator, ProxySQL, MHA,, etc)

Comment: CAPTAIN's LOG SUPPLIEMENTAL : Run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%gtid%';` to see if GTID Replication is in place

Comment: So I didn't see `log_slave_updates` anywhere in the cnf file. However, I do see a few files in the bin log directory that look like relay logs. There's only two though and their timestamps are from a month ago: `mysql-relay-bin-000003`, `mysql-relay-bin-000004`, and `mysql-relay-bin.index`.

Comment: After seeing those I'm guessing it's just artifacts of incorrectly setting up from a bit ago, after running the `stop slave` and `reset slave all` commands the output shows up empty now. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that the master server was in fact also being used as a slave in case of failure. After running `reset slave all` I ran another change master to command and restarted the slave and everything worked out properly.